# Crop OpenCV image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I created a bounding box on the predictions.jpg image using demo.py.

And in Utils.py used in demo.py, I use print to find the coordinates of the upper left and lower right of the bounding box, and I want to crop the image to fit the bounding box using OpenCV below.

How should the coordinate values for each bounding box be loaded into OpenCV and executed???

```
def plot_boxes_cv2(img, boxes, savename=None, class_names=None, color=None):
import cv2
img = np.copy(img)
colors = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]], dtype=np.float32)

def get_color(c, x, max_val):
    ratio = float(x) / max_val * 5
    i = int(math.floor(ratio))
    j = int(math.ceil(ratio))
    ratio = ratio - i
    r = (1 - ratio) * colors[i][c] + ratio * colors[j][c]
    return int(r * 255)

width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    box = boxes[i]
    x1 = int(box[0] * width)
    y1 = int(box[1] * height)
    x2 = int(box[2] * width)
    y2 = int(box[3] * height)

    print("A Coordinate value : ( %s , %s )" % (x1, y1))
    print("B Coordinate value : ( %s , %s )" % (x2, y2))

    import cv2
    img = cv2.imread("predictions.jpg")
    crop_img = img[50:200, 10:200]
    crop_img = img[30:400, 300:40]
    cv2.imshow("orignal",img)
    cv2.imshow("crop",crop_img)
    cv2.imshow("crop2",crop_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 155, in <module>
detect_cv2(args.cfgfile, args.weightfile, args.imgfile)
File "demo.py", line 56, in detect_cv2
plot_boxes_cv2(img, boxes[0], savename='predictions.jpg', class_names=class_names)
File "/home/guest3/Downloads/pytorch-YOLOv4/tool/utils.py", line 129, in plot_boxes_cv2
cv2.imshow("crop",crop_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Comment: Your image is empty! Are you sure this is correct? `crop_img = img[30:400, 300:40]`?  Shouldn't it be 30:40?

Comment: I took the opencv code and this contains random values.
Originally, the coordinates of the top right and bottom left of each bounding box should be in that part.